# What is a true equivalent of `window.onload` for an iron router route in a Meteor.js app?

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have an iron route defined like this (pay attention to `onAfterAction` and `initProfileComponent`)

```
var initProfileComponent = function () {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.sliderComponent');
    //... do stuff and decorate the elements
}

Router.route('newProfile', {
    path: '/new-profile/:_id',
    onAfterAction: function () {
        initProfileComponent();

    },
    data: function () {
        return {profile: Profile.findOne({_id: this.params._id})};
    }
});
```

The function `initProfileComponent` wishes to find using `document.querySelectorAll` elements created by meteor/mustache publish mechanism, that is why is called in `onAfterAction`, but obviously it doesn't work, since, when it is called the elements are not yet rendered.

The templates are defined like this :

```
<template name="newProfile">
    <div class="main-title new-profile">
        new profile
    </div>
    {{#each profile.properties}}
        {{> sliderComponent}}
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="sliderComponent">
    <div class="sliderComponent dragdealer">
        <div class="handle">{{label}}</div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Other than `onAfterAction` which does "buritos" for my use case, where/how can one define an callback that ensures that the template was fully rendered. Or, to what should I subscribe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally this should be done in your template. In Meteor all templates have `onCreated` and `onRendered` callbacks. If you use onRendered, you can be sure that all DOM elements are already there.

```
Template.sliderComponent.onRendered(function(){
    var elements = $('.sliderComponent');
    //... do stuff and decorate the elements
});
```

It is good practice to initialize your template like this. Use Iron Router to parameterize your templates, as you are already doing.

Comment: I don't use jQuery but thank's for pointing that up, to understand, how many times is this `onRendered` callback called ... on every update? meaning if I initialized an widget on an element should I concern about an over init or the old reference is previous elements are unset ?

Comment: Meteor comes with jQuery by default, so you can use it. `onRendered` is always called once, when an instance of the template is rendered for the first time. Please see the documentation: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered